# How can I read a numpy array image with OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a problem which I am trying to solve. I have a `file.npy` containing **a lot of images**.

Each image is a `numpy array` inside that matrix file. so what I want to do is to apply some `cv2` functions on each `numpy array` image inside that matrix. **but I couldn't**. the problem is that `cv2` accept only **file paths**

what I could is to download the image then apply `cv2` functions on it but this method is not applicable and **produce bad performance**.

How can I input a `numpy array` image into `cv2` ?

this is a simple part of my code

```
img=cv2.imread('/content/download.png')

img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#thresholding to remove background
thr = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255,  cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

I have tried this method but it produced error

```
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(some_pic_image), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1) # 'Load it as it is'
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

but error produced?

How can I do that?

Comment: Bu are these images with.npy extension? Because if they are you need numpy load which also requires a path.. You have a file that contains a lot of images, but what is the extension of this file? File or folder? A file also have a path..

Comment: no sorry I mean by file file.npy extension not file path. I modified the question description

Comment: Dou want to post the error you got? This make it easier to debug

Comment: If you have a npy file this file has a path because it is saved somewhere and you need numpy load. If it is instead an already generated array in your script than opencv can already handle it. You might have to change the data type into unsigned 8 bit integers because opencv works on that data type. But anyway it works directly on numpy arrays so there is no need for imread

Comment: Please show some code that creates a representative `.npy` file so we know what we are dealing with, e.g. `green = np.full((8,8,3),[0,255,0], dtype=np.uint8)` and `red = np.full((8,8,3),[255,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)` then `np.save(???)`

Answer (score 0):

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.asarray(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("OpenCV image",image)
cv2.waitKey()
```